# Not delete image from laravel backpack 4.0

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-backpack

I'm using image field in laravel backpack 4.0 and it uploads the images without any problems. When I delete the image by using the `delete button`, it deletes the register (E.N. Probably means "it deletes the image from the database"), but not the image file from my local folder. I've checked the answer from [backpack for laravel deleting image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46078426/backpack-for-laravel-deleting-image) , but it did not help to fix my issue.

My config/filesystem:

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
    ],

],
```

My Model code:

```
public function setImageAttribute($value)
{
    $attribute_name = "image";
    $disk = config('backpack.base.root_disk_name'); // or use your own disk, defined in config/filesystems.php
    $destination_path = env('FOLDER_PUBLIC')."/uploads/medias"; // path relative to the disk above

    // if the image was erased
    if ($value==null) {
        // delete the image from disk
        \Storage::disk($disk)->delete($this->{$attribute_name});

        // set null in the database column
        $this->attributes[$attribute_name] = null;
    }

    // if a base64 was sent, store it in the db
    if (starts_with($value, 'data:image'))
    {
        // 0. Make the image
        $image = \Image::make($value)->encode('jpg', 90);
        // 1. Generate a filename.
        $filename = rand ( 10000 , 99999 ).'-'.strtolower(trim(preg_replace('/[\s-]+/', '-', preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/', '-', preg_replace('/[&]/', 'and', preg_replace('/[\']/', '', iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $this->title))))), '-')).'.jpg';

        // 2. Store the image on disk.
        \Storage::disk($disk)->put($destination_path.'/'.$filename, $image->stream());
        // 3. Save the public path to the database
        // but first, remove "public/" from the path, since we're pointing to it from the root folder
        // that way, what gets saved in the database is the user-accesible URL
        $public_destination_path = Str::replaceFirst(env('FOLDER_PUBLIC').'/', '', $destination_path);
        $this->attributes[$attribute_name] = $public_destination_path.'/'.$filename;
    }
}
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function($obj) {

        \Storage::disk('public')->delete($obj->image);
    });
}
```

I have tried to change:

```
\Storage::disk('public')->delete($obj->image);
```

With:

```
\Storage::disk(config('backpack.base.root_disk_name'))->delete($obj->image);
```

But it is not working either,

Can anyone help me?

Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. Looks like something is misconfigured if code in `boot()` doesn't affect any changes. My guess is that that the `$obj->image` path to the file you're trying to delete is NOT the exact path to the file. You might need to add the destination folder there too.

```php
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function($obj) {
        $disk = config('backpack.base.root_disk_name');
        $destination_path = env('FOLDER_PUBLIC')."/uploads/medias";
        \Storage::disk($disk)->delete($destination_path.'/'.$this->image);
    });
}
```

If this works, to further improve the code, I recommend you turn the `$disk` and `$destination_path` variables into properties on the PHP class itself (the Laravel model). That way, you only define them in one place, and you can then use them in both methods, with something like `$this->imageDisk` and `$this->imagePath`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply, At the end I have fixed it, making this change:

```
 public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function($obj) {

        \Storage::disk('uploads')->delete($obj->image);
    });
}
```

And in config/filesystem:

'disks' => [

```
    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
    ],
    'uploads' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
       /* 'root'   => base_path().'/web/storage',*/
        'root'   => base_path().'/'.env('FOLDER_PUBLIC'),
    ],

],
```

Regards